# Homogenous Universe (Earthlike planets?)

Tags: cosmology, symmetry, astrophysics, universe, structure-formation

The fact that the Universe is homogenous can lead to a conclusion that there are another earthlike planets, or planets like earth are considered as some differences that are allowed in the definition of the homogeneity of the Universe?

Comment: Roughly homogenous on large scales would probably be a more accurate statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is not correct but the final conclusion is!

There are other earth-like planets because there are so many galaxies, stars and planets AND All these object follow the same rules.

The universe could still have many earth like planets even if it was not homogeneous at large scale. When population is large, rare phenomena can happen a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the homogeneity of the universe logically implies the probable existence of more earthlike planets than just ours- but this conclusion is at present hard to prove by astronomical observations.

Comment: Re "probable existence of more earthlike planets than just ours", I do not have a clear concept of what this means. Re "probable", to understand this I think a range of probability values would be very helpful. For example, it might mean that there must be at least one chance in a thousand that somewhere in the observable universe there is another planet with characteristics similar enough to the Earth's characteristics to qualify as "similar to ours". Also the characteristics necessary for some other planet to qualify  as "similar to ours" needs to be specified.

Answer (score 0):

If the universe was infinite and homogeneous, there were no planets at all! Planets form due to overdensities. Overdensities are inhomogeneities. So strictly speaking, in a homogeneous universe, nothing would form, as nothing collapses as everything is as strongly attracted in one direction as in the exact opposite direction.

Comment: With this view , why we consider the universe homogenous ? We consider it as homogenous on average , where overdensities are evened out by something else ?

Comment: I would rather say that to consider it as homogeneous is a zero-order approximation.

Answer (score 0):

The homogeneity of the universe has NO relationship whatsoever to planets. Homogeneity is about common characteristics for very large volumes, like e.g., like a sphere a billion light years in diameter. At the scale of planets or their orbits, there is no assumption of any homogeneity.